# Grouping logical data in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that contains data of 0 & 1. I want to find groups of ones (not a specific size) in that matrix. Is it possible somehow? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want to find all the "connected components in the matrix, say `BW`, simply use:

```
BW = logical([1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
              1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
              1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
              1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
              1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
              1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
              1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
              1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]);

L = bwlabel(BW,4)    %Result
```

This would yeild:

```
L =

     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     2     2     0     0
     1     1     1     0     2     2     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     3     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     3     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     3     0
     1     1     1     0     0     3     3     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
```

Now if you want to find the size of various groups:

```
for ii=1:max(L(:))
    length_vector(ii)=length(find(L==ii));
end
length_vector
```

This gives you:

```
length_vector =

    24     4     5
```